# Flyers for people to use

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'll be at the [Steampunk World's Fair](http://www.oneiroievents.com/thesteampunkworldsfair/) in Somerset, NJ this weekend, an excellent opportunity to pass out flyers for this site. Especially at the [tweed ride](http://www.oneiroievents.com/thesteampunkworldsfair/?p=3254) on Sunday.

Anyone have any input on flyers? What should they say? Gonna print something up this afternoon, but have no clue what text to use, help!

---

Edit: Ended up using the flyer below. Feel free to copy, change, et cetera.

Comment: Awesome - this is headed straight for the office locker rooms!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have done a quick flyer. I chose example questions that would appeal to people at this specific event. If anyone wants to use this, feel free.

(It's a faux-victorian/steampunk event, so the style here is (if anything) not overwrought enough.)

---

5.5 x 8.5 flyer, front and back:

[image]

---

Here's [a printable PDF version](http://baroqueandhungry.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/bicycles-flyer.pdf) (warning: large file with embedded fonts.) You can use this for two-sided printing, then chop the page in half.

Comment: this is so awesome!

Comment: This is awesome indeed! I love the design. The typography, art work and even the copy are all excellent!

Comment: @Jin - Any thoughts how I could redesign this for the Steampunk World's Fair 2012? Incorporating the new design with this would be an interesting challenge.

Comment: @NeilFein I emailed you an illustrator file. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jin - Thanks! File received.