# Promoting Bicycles.StackExchange at work

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I work in a coworking space with several other keen cyclists. I've mentioned this site to the ones I know, but I was wondering if you have any posters, stickers or other promotional stuff that I can put up to try and entice the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we do! There's [a thread with flyers you can use](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/flyers-for-people-to-use), as well as [a thread with text](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/one-short-paragraph-that-describes-this-site) you can put into your own promotional materials.